# Ofuscar parte do background-image, e deixando nítida outras partes

Tags: html5, css3

Estou tentando reproduzir [este](https://dribbble.com/shots/2144170-Day-014-Location-Card/attachments/392323) "exemplo" do Dribble, entretanto não estou conseguindo. Meu progresso atual é [este](https://codepen.io/Mercurionn/pen/MXavvw?editors=1100) (utilizando SCSS), entretanto como pode-se verificar eu dupliquei o *background* para alcançar esse efeito, para as imagens ficarem alinhadas exatamente uma em cima da outra tive que usar o `background-position: center;` o que não é o desejado (gostaria de usar a propriedade *cover*). Como posso fazer esse "efeito" usando apenas uma imagem de *background*?

Compilando o SCSS para CSS, fica assim:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
}

#container {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #202020;
  width: 800px;
  height: 280px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background-image: url(https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/usa-new-york-panorama-sunrise-71107239.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto;
  background-position: center;
  background-color: darkslategray;
  background-blend-mode: overlay;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#main {
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: url(https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/usa-new-york-panorama-sunrise-71107239.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto;
  background-position: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="main">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Opção 1**

Vc pode usar `mix-blend-mode:overlay` no elemento que está por cima da imagem. Aqui é importante que esse elemento seja na cor branca para o `overlay` ficar bom, vc pode controlar a intensidade dele com o `opacity`

**OBS:** repare que eu mantive o `background-blend-mode:color-burn` no bg do pai, e também usei o `size` dele como `cover` sem problemas.

```css
#container {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #202020;
  width: 800px;
  height: 280px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,50,50,0.5) 0%, rgba(0,50,50,0.5) 100%), url(https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/usa-new-york-panorama-sunrise-71107239.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-blend-mode: color-burn;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  /* box-shadow: 0 0 0px 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.5) inset; */
}

#main {
    background-color: #fff;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: auto;
    background-position: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    mix-blend-mode: overlay;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="main">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Opção 2:**

Se os cantos arredondados não forem problema vc consegue esse resultado usando um `inset` `box-shadow`

Veja o resultado no exemplo abaixo:

```css
#container {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #202020;
  width: 800px;
  height: 280px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background-image: url(https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/usa-new-york-panorama-sunrise-71107239.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0px 50px rgba(0,50,50,0.5) inset;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="main">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Hugo, funcionou!